# Alternative Solution to Hartshorne exercise II.4.2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I managed to solve II.4.2 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry in the following way, but had played around with a different, more elegant solution, but wasn't able to make it work. I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to make this argument, or something similar to it work, for reference here is the problem statement.

Let $S$ be a scheme, let $X$ be a reduced scheme over $S$, and let $Y$ be a separated scheme over $S$. Let $f$ and $g$ be two $S$-morphisms which agree on an open dense subset of $X$. Show that $f = g$.

My solution was as follows:
Let $h\colon X\to Y\times_S Y$ be the map obtained by looking at $f,g$, then let $\Delta\colon Y\to Y\times_S Y$ be the diagonal morphism. Since $Y$ is separated it follows that $\Delta(Y)$ is closed, and since $h$ is continuous $h^{-1}(\Delta(Y))$ is closed, and one can show that $U$ is a subset of $h^{-1}(\Delta(Y))$ so that it is equal to $X$. From here one can show that $f,g$ agree as topological maps by noting that $f = \rho_1\circ h$, $g = \rho_2\circ h$, and then noting that for any point $x \in X$ that $h(x) = \Delta(y)$ for some $y \in Y$. We then turn our attention to showing that the map of sheaves are the same, noting that we have not yet used the hypothesis that $X$ is reduced.

From here, since we can show the sheaf maps agree locally we can assume that $X,Y$ are affine, and then if $X = \text{Spec }A$ then for any $a \in A$ if we set $b = f^\#(a) - g^\#(a)$ we see that $b|_U = 0$ from which it follows that $U \subseteq V(b)$, but then $V(b) = X$ implying that $b$ is nilpotent, and thus $0$ implying that $f^\#,g^\#$ agree.

Now one idea I played around was to show that $f,g$ agree as maps of schemes after showing that $X = h^{-1}(\Delta(Y))$ was by noting that $\Delta$ is a closed immersion, so that $Y$ is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $Y\times_S Y$, then since $X$ is reduced the scheme-theoretic image of $h$ is simply the reduced induced subscheme structure on the closure of $h(X)$. This implies that $h$ factors through $h(X)$ which is a subset of $\Delta(Y)$, and if we can show that $h$ factors through $Y$ (considered as a closed subscheme), say as $\iota\circ h'$ where $\iota$ is the inclusion of $Y$ into $Y\times_S Y$, then we know that $f = \rho_1\circ h = \rho_1\circ\iota\circ h' = h'$ (I believe the last equality should be true?) then we can similarly get that $g = \rho_2\circ h = \rho_2\circ\iota\circ h' = h'$ to get that $f = g$, but I wasn't sure if this is possible. I tried to play around with trying to show that somehow the inclusion of the scheme-theoretic image $h(X)\to Y\times_S Y$ factors through $Y$ by noting that $h(X) \subseteq \Delta(Y)$ but wasn't able to get anywhere with this. Is this one way to tackle this problem? Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier way to do this is to consider the following pullback square, where we write $V=X\times_{Y\times_S Y} Y$ for neatness:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{}>> Y\\
@VVV @VV{\Delta_{Y/S}}V \\
X @>{(f\times_S g)}>> Y\times_S Y
\end{CD}$$

As $Y\to S$ is separated, $\Delta_{Y/S}$ is a closed immersion. As closed immersions are stable under base change, the map $V\to X$ is a closed immersion. The image of $V$ is a closed subscheme containing $U$, so $V\to X$ is a closed immersion which has set-theoretic image all of $X$. But the only such closed immersion into a reduced scheme is an isomorphism (check this affine-locally).